# Windows 7 Computer crashing in seemingly random ways. How to determine root cause?

Tags: windows-7, crash

Windows 7 machine keeps crashing. It happens with various software packages and seems pretty random except that I have usually "dome something" like click or hover the mouse over the task bar. The "something" varies with every crash.

My question is what would be a good way to track this down to root cause? I have in the past tried memory checking, drive checking and hardware checking of various kinds. Is there an app that can keep an eye on things and report (in a meaningful way) what happened?

The computer specs:
[image: Computer specs from System Information]

Comment: `windbg` is extremely helpful in a case like this.

Comment: first thing I would do is log in windows in safe mode and try to get it to crash. if it does crash then it could be hardware or NOT driver related. if it doesnt then it could be driver or services or a software related in windows.